# Pandas read_excel converting 0 and 1 to True and False

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a script that converts and combines excel spreadsheets. I have around 50 worksheets which all have the same format. The only problem I run in is when I append the dataframes together. 0s and 1s are converted to False and True when they should not. I have looked at documentation but I cant find anything to help me. I believe the problem is when I use pd.ExcelFile(workbook). Here is my code

```
xlsx_files = glob.glob("*.xlsx")
combined_df = pd.DataFrame()
for workbook in xlsx_files:
    excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(workbook)
    worksheets = excel_file.sheet_names
    for worksheet in worksheets:
        worksheet_df = excel_file.parse(worksheet)
        combined_df = combined_df.append(worksheet_df, ignore_index=True)
        # worksheet_df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, worksheet=worksheet)
```

Here is the original worksheet information

```
Observed Value  Values Count 
**0     52708**
0.00825 4
0.0055  4
0.04    12
0.0075  2
0.00549 3
0.01    74
0.0036  2
0.03    21
0.0095  4
0.00634 3
0.00375 2
0.02    7
0.009   8
0.0085  2
0.007   2
0.008   6
0.00675 2
0.00577 3
0.00583 3
0.0065  8
0.0025  3
0.05    5
0.00625 4
0.005   2
0.0015  2
```

Here is output my code prints out

```
Observed Value  Values Count
**FALSE 52708**
0.00825 4
0.0055  4
0.04    12
0.0075  2
0.00549 3
0.01    74
0.0036  2
0.03    21
0.0095  4
0.00634 3
0.00375 2
0.02    7
0.009   8
0.0085  2
0.007   2
0.008   6
0.00675 2
0.00577 3
0.00583 3
0.0065  8
0.0025  3
0.05    5
0.00625 4
0.005   2
0.0015  2
```

I am trying to get rid of the False value, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: can you change the 0 to 0.0 and check if the error is still occurring?

Comment: That's a very strange result as only a single data point changes but not the entire column type from numeric to boolean. By title of your question, I had assumed 0s, 1s columns were casted to boolean series.

Comment: And as I assumed, I cannot reproduce your issue with or without asterisks using [ExcelFile.parse](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html) or [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_excel.html). With asterisks, columns are *object* types and without, columns are *float* and *int* respectively. Carefully check if data was not FALSE to begin with as you can get confused with 50 sheets! And even check Excel column's number format.

Comment: The column contains both strings and numerics but for some reason the 0s and 1s are converted to false and true. I tried changing the 0 to 0.0 in excel but python still converts the values to booleans.

Comment: I really doubt Python, a strong-type language, is implicitly casting types like this. Again, with your posted data I cannot reproduce your issue. Try importing the problem Excel file that this occurs by itself (outside of loop). Also, please list out your environment in post: python version, pandas version, OS, virtualenv, MS office version, etc.

Comment: I tried running the code on a smaller sample and it seems to not give me this problem, but once I start using more files, the problem returns. I am using Python 2.7.14, Padnas 20.3, Windows 10, Excel 2010

Comment: I think the following post answers this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56614576/excel-file-containing-both-boolean-and-0-and-or-1-in-same-column-not-importe/