# Excel file containing both boolean and "0" and/or "1" in same column not imported correctly with read_excel

Tags: python, pandas

I need to import an excel sheet as is in a dataframe in pandas. When using the `read_excel` function with `dtype=object`, I still get "interpreted" values.

I am using Python 3.5.4, pandas 0.23.4 in anaconda environment.

My (test) excel sheet:

```
header1 header2 header3 header4 header5 header6 mixed
word11  word12  word13  word14  word15  word16  word17
word21  word22  word23  word24  word25  word26  word27
TRUE    1       FALSE   0       TRUE    1       TRUE
word41  word42  word43  word44  word45  word46  0
0       TRUE    0       TRUE    TRUE    0       FALSE
1       FALSE   1       FALSE   FALSE   1       1
word71  word72  word73  word74  word75  word76  word77
```

So I import and print:

```py
sheets_dict = pd.read_excel(reqFile, sheet_name=[1],dtype=object)
sheets_dict[list(sheets_dict.keys())[0]]
```

Imported dataframe:

```
  header1 header2 header3 header4 header5 header6   mixed
0  word11  word12  word13  word14  word15  word16  word17
1  word21  word22  word23  word24  word25  word26  word27
2    True       1   False       0    True       1    True
3  word41  word42  word43  word44  word45  word46       0
4       0       1   False    True    True       0       0
5    True   False       1       0   False       1    True
6  word71  word72  word73  word74  word75  word76  word77
```

Column1:
For columns containing a `True`, followed by a `1`, the `1` is loaded into the dataframe as `True` as well.

Column2:
The opposite happens as well: if a `1` appears first in the column, followed by a `True`, the `True` is loaded as `1` in the dataframe.

Column3:
`False` makes all subsequent `0` to be converted into `False`

Column4:
Opposite column3

Column5/6:
all good

Column7:
First `True` switches all subsequent `1`'s to `True`, while the first `0` converts all subsequent `False` to `0`.

How can I force `read_excel` to not interpret anything and read the Excel sheet as is? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: set `dtype=object` in `read_excel`. Does it help?

Comment: I am using dtype=object already, but does not seem to help

Answer (score 2):

You can force pandas to set column type to **str** instead of auto-converting to boolean and integer in an unpredictable way. If this works, you can insert a conditional so that only "TRUE" and "FALSE" are converted into boolean, and numbers 1 and 0 are converted into int type. The **converters** parameter takes a dictionary.

```
'df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1', header=0,          
                    converters={'header1':str,'header2':str})'
```

Comment: This works! I just need to create a converter dictionary to cover my whole range of columns. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

So to force what i need i did the following:

```py
sheets_dict = pd.read_excel(reqFile, sheet_name=[1],dtype=object)
keys = sheets_dict[list(sheets_dict.keys())[0]].keys()
values = [str] * len(keys)
convertDict = dict(zip(keys, values))
sheets_dict = pd.read_excel(reqFile, sheet_name=[1],dtype=object,converters=convertDict)
```

Like this i get an exact copy of my excel sheet:

```
  header1 header2 header3 header4 header5 header6   mixed
0  word11  word12  word13  word14  word15  word16  word17
1  word21  word22  word23  word24  word25  word26  word27
2    True       1   False       0    True       1    True
3  word41  word42  word43  word44  word45  word46       0
4       0    True       0    True    True       0   False
5       1   False       1   False   False       1       1
6  word71  word72  word73  word74  word75  word76  word77
```

Only disadvantage is that i need to read in the sheet twice.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I used Werner's solution but I think I improved it. Including nrows=0 should make it less of an issue to read the data twice.

```
dataFrame = pandas.read_excel(workbook, sheetName, dtype=object, nrows=0)
converters = {column:str for column in dataFrame.columns}
dataFrame = pandas.read_excel(workbook, sheetName, converters=converters)
```

Trying to read in strings with pandas has had some interesting history and is still being worked on:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20377

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html

I personally find it strange that dtype=str doesn't just give you all str values. Why should you have to create a converter for each column that says the exact same thing?